# Select from 2 rows in one table into a single row with 2 or more columns in the second table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that has 2 columns. One is a type column and the other is a value amount column. There are only 2 types/ I would like to select columns of this table into another table with 2 combined columns based on type and value. For example, the table may have order with 2 of the types in 2 rows. It would be inserted into the 2nd table as one row.

Example:

Table 1

| ID   | OrderID  | Type         |  Value |
|:-----|:--------:|:------------:|-------:|
| 1    | 300      | bike         | 100    |
| 2    | 300      | skateboard   | 150    |
| 3    | 700      | bike         | 200    |
| 4    | 700      | skateboard   | 50     |
| 5    | 800      | bike         | 150    |
| 6    | 800      | skateboard   | 100    _
What is the TSQL to have it inserted into the 2nd table with these values?
Table 2
| ID  | OrderID  | BikeValue  |  SkateboardValue |
|:----|:--------:|:----------:|-----------------:|
| 1   | 300      | 100        | 150              |
| 2   | 700      | 200        | 50               |
| 3   | 800      | 150        | 100              |

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple for yourself.  Do two SQL statements.  One to insert and another to update.

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (OrderID, BikeValue)
SELECT Table1.OrderID, Table1.Value
FROM Table1 (NOLOCK) 
WHERE Table1.Type = 'bike'

UPDATE Table2 SET Table2.SkateboardValue = Table1.Value 
FROM Table2 
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.OrderID = Table2.OrderID 
WHERE Table1.Type = 'skateboard'
```